# Getting Rid of blanks spaces without the use of Most API

Tags: java

Having trouble getting a grip around how to do this, because I have to use a string and can only use `subString` and `charAt` for the program. I thought of ways of arrays, and everything in that nature, but when I think of the string I get lost. Finding the beginning and maybe even the end of a word would be easy but we must also worry about the middle spaces as well.

Example: `"     Walking         Dead      "` => `"Walking Dead"`

Any suggestions on what I am maybe thinking wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your question how to remove blank spaces in a string using only charAt() and substring()?

Comment: What is your current solution? If you post your current thoughts of how to solve the problem, maybe we can find the errors and guide you on the right path.

Comment: ive tried writing it out, and i cant come up with anything, i do not want the code given to me, but i feel like im missing something about a string. My thoughts atm are to search the string for a value > than 32 and make that the beginning string. Then maybe breaking off that loop and finding the end of the actual word of the string and declaring it as its own string, and keep repeating till all the words are done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use length(), one solution is to loop through the chars in the string and add the non-spaces to a new string:

```
public static String removeSpaces(String test) {
    String noSpaces = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        if (test.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            noSpaces += test.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return noSpaces;
}
```

There are a lot of ways to do this though.

Comment: okay thanks for the advice, wasnt sure if being able to initialize a new string with an old string was a thing or how to do it.